# HP Envy x360 Display Won't Turn On When Lid Closed

Tags: display, suspend

I have Ubuntu 22.10 installed on my HP Envy x360 laptop. I love the OS and have adopted it as my main partition since I'm a programmer and it really helps me with development. However, when I close the lid of my laptop for an extended period of time (maybe 15 min+) and I reopen my laptop to use it again, the display is completely black and won't turn on. I know the computer is still running because my keyboard lights up and I can hear my laptop fans running. This forces me to forcibly turn off my laptop, essentially rendering sleep useless, and putting me in danger of corrupting the state of my OS. Any ideas of how to resolve this issue?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Before risking the loss of any unsaved session data on your laptop, I'd suggest you do some troubleshooting first to get suspend (and perhaps even hibernate) to work correctly. To start out, in a more controlled session (no open apps where you could lose data), try running `sudo systemctl suspend.` This will suspend your machine without needing to close the lid. Then press a key (ESC) and see if everything comes back. If not run `sudo dmesg` (or `sudo journalctl --dmesg`) and report back any errors (likely ACPI-related).

Comment: @richbl Hi, thanks so much for your reply! I tried this out but I have a hard time figuring out how I can run the second command if my screen doesn't turn back on. As an update, it seems like the very first time I suspend my computer the screen is able to turn back on without an issue, but afterward, any suspend will cause my screen to go black without recovery. Any tips as to how to proceed?

Comment: The first command will confirm the suspend issue, while the second command will log the event, and any subsequent warnings/errors that result from the failed suspend (even after reboot, you should have that data logged). So, after an attempt to suspend (which fails), and a subsequent reboot, check the logs and you might see something of value to leads to clues (typically ACPI-related log warnings/errors). Good luck.

Comment: @richbl Thanks for the clarification, here are the errors returned from my second attempt of suspending. The first attempt saw the same errors bar the last one. 
`[    0.356930] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.GPP0.DEV0], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
[    0.356944] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[    1.650803] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[   10.185203] hp_wmi: query 0x4c returned error 0x6
[ 1318.959156] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ELAN2514:00: PM: failed to resume async: error -121 `

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by upgrading my Linux kernel. Turns out this was a bug with the AMD GPU driver.